# Corrupt sudoers files ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sudo

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on an AWS instance, and accessed it via a putty session as ubuntu (using the AWS generated key).

I wanted to allow password based login, and I modified the ssh_login and sshd_login to allow password based authentication.

Then I screwed up, and manually edited the /etc/sudoers files

```
sudo vi sudoers
```

and saved the file. I made a syntax error in sudoers. I am now stuck.

Yes, I should have used pkexec visudo, but I did not. Any idea how to fix this? This is a remote system, so I cannot reboot in debug mode, or use a USB to reboot.

Comment: [These instructions](https://n2ws.com/blog/how-to-guides/connect-aws-ebs-volume-another-instance) might enable you to mount and edit `/etc/sudoers` in another instance. I'm a bit rushed, so I didn't verify that it can do that.

Comment: Yes, this will work, but this is the only disk, and I freeze the instance, I will not be able to "re-attach" it, nothing to attach it to

Comment: "I should have used pkexec visudo" ... and you still can.